# Rails - Controller Create method not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

I'm creating new users in a rails app. I have the form set up okay and now looking at the methods in my controller. This is what I have for the new and create actions -

```
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)

    if @user.save
      redirect_to @user, notice: "Welcome to Safeguarding Monitor."
    else
      render 'new'
    end

  end
```

These are the user params -

```
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:firstname, :surname, :nickname, :email, :timezone )
end
```

When I fill out the form it just redirects to new. It isn't saving the user and I can't seem to see why. I've been away from rails for a bit and can't quite work out why this is happening.

This is the form -

```
<% provide :title, "Add Staff Member" %>

<%= form_for @user do |f| %>

  <div class="form-group row">
    <%= f.label :firstname, 'First Name', class: 'col-sm-2' %>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <%= f.text_field :firstname, class: 'form-control' %>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group row">
    <%= f.label :nickname, 'Nickname', class: 'col-sm-2' %>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <%= f.text_field :nickname, class: 'form-control' %>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group row">
    <%= f.label :surname, 'Last Name', class: 'col-sm-2' %>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <%= f.text_field :surname, class: 'form-control' %>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group row">
    <%= f.label :email, 'Email Address', class: 'col-sm-2' %>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <%= f.email_field :email, class: 'form-control' %>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group row">
    <%= f.label :email, 'Send Welcome Email?', class: 'col-sm-2' %>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <%= check_box_tag :send_welcome_email %>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group row">
    <%= f.label :current_school_id, 'School Group', class: 'col-sm-2' %>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
     <%= f.text_field :current_school_id, class: 'form-control' %>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group row">
    <%= f.label :timezone, 'Timezone', class: 'col-sm-2' %>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <%= f.time_zone_select(:timezone, nil, {default: @user.timezone}, {class: 'form-control custom-select'}) %>
    </div>
  </div>

  <hr>

  <h2>Create Password</h2>

  <p><small>Password must be at least six characters long</small></p>

  <div class="form-group row">
    <%= f.label :password, 'New Password', class: 'col-sm-2' %>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off", class: 'form-control' %>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group row">
    <%= f.label :password_confirmation, 'Confirm Password', class: 'col-sm-2' %>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "off", class: 'form-control' %>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit 'Submit', class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**UPDATE -**

I got through to the show page and got an error which I appeared to fix with this action -

```
def show
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end
```

However, whilst this method has appeared to fix things on the site. The User profile is not saving on the database and when I check the rails console the last user is not the one I've created. Is there a different method I should be using?

Comment: you must be getting some error, in the else block of `if @user.save` do a `puts @user.errors` and see if you get anything

Comment: Rather `puts @user.errors.messages` :)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `password` and `password_confirmation` to your `user_params`

It will be

```
 params.require(:user).permit(:firstname, :surname, :nickname, :email, :timezone,  :password, :password_confirmation)
```

Update the `create` method like this

```
def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    respond_to do |format|
        if @user.save
            flash[:notice] = 'User was successfully created.'
            format.html { redirect_to user_path(@user) }
        else
            flash[:notice] = 'Something went wrong.'
            format.html { render :action => "new" }
            # or
            # format.html { redirect_to new_user_path }
        end
    end
end
```

It should work

Comment: @MikeWhitehead Lets try the solution and let me know that what's happening

Answer (score 0):

After `save` you have to check if there are any errors.

```
def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    @user.save

    unless @user.errors.any?
        #puts @user.errors.full_messages 
        redirect_to @user, notice: "Welcome to Safeguarding Monitor."
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end
```

Check your permitted params as [fool-dev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4172515/fool-dev) advised.

Comment: That's definitely moved things forward, now getting a 'no method' error in Users*show

Comment: I've updated my question above with further details. It's working on the site but the user profile isn't saving to the database.

Comment: Take a look at `@user.errors.full_messages` output in `#create` action. It seams that there some errors.

Answer (score 0):

There might be some validaton errors due to which record is not get saved and new page is again get rendered.

add code to display validation error messages on view, so you will came to know what mistake you are doing.

Comment: also add permitted params as suggested by @fool-dev